# Load Message Properties form another maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have couple of maven projects:

```
mainProject(WAR)

 - messages.properties
 - messages_pt.properties
 - messages_ja.properties

projectForTesting(JAR)
```

Any of the above knows nothing about the other one.

My goal is to provide internationalization with ResourceBundleMessageSource for **projectForTesting** based on **messages.properties** from **mainProject**.

I've tried to play with:

> maven-war-plugin

but, I am not sure whether it will be correct one.

It will be good to know how can I correctly add dependency for **projectForTesting** that all properties from **mainProject** will be accessible.

Comment: You can make third project with internalization only and add dependency of new project to mainProject and projectForTesting

Comment: No, unfortunately, I can't create third project. I should do it in scope of projectForTesting, because internationalization will be developed only for projectForTesting.

Comment: You can just package these properties (with the assembly plugin), and use/unzip this dependency on your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already fixed this stuff in the following way:

I've added to pom.xml of **mainProject**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
            <packagingIncludes>**/*.properties,**/*.class</packagingIncludes>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Then add dependency for **projectForTesting**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>mainProject</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
```